# How to set RecognizerIntent for all of the languages

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition

Is it possible to make RecognizerIntent, or any other way to use speech recognition in android, to detect the language that you're talking, and send the result in that language. Like, if I say a romanian word, to detect that it is romanian, then send me that word? Are there any other options for speech recognition rather than RecognizerIntent? I have an app that actually combines words, like, if I say a word in french then one in english, it will actually combine them, like "I like filles".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `android.speech` APIs (`RecognizerIntent`, `RecognitionListener`, ...) do not offer anything towards multi-language speech recognition nor language detection. You would need to find a service that offers these and interact with it directly, by-passing the standard Android APIs.